# Python Class Closure: Is It What It Called?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, closures

I know high order functions and closure that is created with function returns. In most of the cases I find it useful and use it repetitively. My question here is related to the closure that is created with class definition and referencing a class instance's function that is returned from a function call. Can this be categorized as regular closure or is it something else in the Python (or programming) literature? Here is an example:

```
class Klass:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def ret_val(self):
        return self.val


def gen_val_fn(val):
    inst = Klass(val)
    return inst.ret_val

fn5 = gen_val_fn(5)
fn6 = gen_val_fn(6)

print("first: {}".format(fn5()))
print("second: {}".format(fn6()))
```

How does the internals work here? My assumption here is after `gen_val_fn(5)` call, the first instance of Klass is created and it is not garbage collected until the `fn5` is garbage collected. So it is able to be able to create `val=5` as closure (I am not sure this can be the right terminology). Is there any document or internal knowledge that you can point out on this? Or explain it if this explanation has flaws.

Thanks!

Comment: There are no closures here. `val` is just an attribute.

Comment: Closures only apply to _functions defined within other functions_. What you're referring to is simply an instance attribute.

Comment: @Daniel: Surely fn5 references a bound method inst.ret_val.

Comment: it is really amazing find your question, I am recently find that class is just an alternative of a closure.

Comment: @alexHall The closure is the gen_val_fn, the enclosed variable is inst.

Comment: @gbtimmon `inst` is a local variable. That doesn't make `gen_val_fn` a function. Christian's point that "Closures only apply to functions defined within other functions" is correct, and there are no such nested functions here.

Comment: @AlexHall I suppose you're not wrong, the way you phrased you comment made it seem like you were talking about something other then what was being asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is called a bound method.

A bound method holds reference to the instance (i.e. `self`) and the function, so when it is called, the `self` is inserted into the list of arguments.
The `self` then, of course holds references to all other member variables.

In your example, try this:

```
>>> fn5
<bound method Klass.ret_val of <__main__.Klass object at 0x006B1270>>
>>> fn5.__self__
<__main__.Klass object at 0x006B1270>
>>> fn5.__self__.val
5
```

Then, calling `fn5()` is the same as calling `fn5.__func__(fn5.__self__)`.